# HTML5 RNC- datatype library "http://whattf.org/datatype-draft" not recognized

Tags: schema, relaxng, relaxng-compact

I tried to validate my HTML5 document against the Nu RNC set available in github.com/validator/validator/tree/master/schema/html using jing, I ended up with  "datatype library "http://whattf.org/datatype-draft not recognized" error. I am not sure what is the error all about. Is it not possible to validate the HTML5 using this RNC set in jing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainer of the https://github.com/validator/validator/tree/master/schema/html5 schema here.

That schema’s not really meant for use outside the context of the [Nu Html Checker](https://validator.github.io/validator/). Among other things, it relies on a datatype library—set of Java classes—we don’t package/distribute separately.

The lack of it in your classpath causes the *“Datatype library… not recognized”* error you cite. For it to work, in your classpath you need to have a jar file with those classes and a special manifest.

We do distribute a jar file that contains those, but with a lot of other things too—the jar is 22MB.
You can get that (zipped) jar from here:

https://github.com/validator/validator/releases/download/17.3.0/vnu.jar_17.3.0.zip

Once you unzip that, you’ll have a local `vnu.jar` file, which you can use like this:

```
java -cp vnu.jar com.thaiopensource.relaxng.util.Driver \
  -c https://raw.github.com/validator/validator/master/schema/html5/xhtml5.rnc \
  FILE.xhtml
```

Of course if you have a local clone of the https://github.com/validator/validator repo, then you can replace https://raw.github.com/validator/validator/master/schema/html5/xhtml5.rnc with the filesystem path to the local copy of that `xhtml5.rnc` file.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to compile the jar file from the cloned copy of validator  https://github.com/validator/validator with the local copy of html.rnc. But I am getting the error  Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.Main. Is there any way to handle the data types in RNC which are used in datatype.jar ?

Comment: The ant classes are in jar files in the `jing-trang/lib` directory. If you build the validator jar by running `./build/build.sh update dldeps build jar` the build script finds the dependency jars on its own and uses them in its build classpath.

Comment: Thank you! I can build Jar, but while testing it getting `Could not find or load main class nu.validator.client.SimpleCommandLineValidator` I can't use that Jar to run in command line `java -jar vnu.jar File.html`

Comment: Probably best to post a new question at this point, or actually better yet to open a new issue at https://github.com/validator/validator/issues. Please show the exact command you’re running, along with exactly how you built the jar